# Display an image based on dropdown selection

Tags: objective-c

[**See this image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R07xz.png)
In my application i wright the complete code for dropdown menu.
**My Question is** : if User select show 5 option from `DropDown` list then it display  5 image Same as if user select Show 3 option from `dropDown` menu it will display 3 image on screen How??

On Button Action  method

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender
{

if (self.tableView.hidden == YES)
        self.tableView.hidden=NO;
    else
        self.tableView.hidden=YES;


}
```

image  screen shot:
here i attach image  please check it ..

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the selected index of the dropdown, you could use the index to get the image name/image Url from an array at that index. So say you selected drop down 5, you could then check that index in the imageArray[4].

So as long as dropDown has some sort of index logic and if it is a class level object, you will be able to get the image from the array at the selected index like below. If dropDown doesn't have an index that gets stored you could also set the tag of dropDown and then use imageArray[_dropDown.tag].

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {
    NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"imgOne", @"imgTwo", imgThree", @"imgFour", @"imgFive", nil];
    UIImageView *imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageArray[_dropDown.selectedIndex]];
    }
```

Let me know if this helps get you in the right direction.